# php + ajax without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to update a status in my users table - when a user click on a button I used ajax to send it to the the php page but on response the page reload because I used `location.reload();. Is there a way i could make the button change its status without reloading the page?

The buttons:

```
<i data="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="status_checks btn <?php echo ($row['payment_status'])? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'?>"><?php echo ($row['payment_status'])? 'Paid' : 'Unpaid'?></i>
```

php that update the database

```
<?php 
extract($_POST);
$user_id=$db->real_escape_string($id);
$status=$db->real_escape_string($status);
$sql=$db->query("UPDATE users SET payment_status='$status' WHERE id='$id'");
echo $sql;

?>
```

and finally, the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.status_checks',function(){
var status = ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) ? 'Unpaid' : 'Paid';
var msg = (status=='Unpaid')? 'Unpaid' : 'Paid';
if(confirm("Are you sure to "+ msg)){
    var current_element = $(this);
    url = "update.php";
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: url,
    data: {id:$(current_element).attr('data'),status:status},
    success: function(data)
        {   
            location.reload();
        }
    });
    }      
});
</script>
```

Comment: instead of reload adjust the value of the `div` or whatever element you are using to display the status

Answer (score 0):

`echo $sql;` will return either 0 or 1

you can update the class of the button without reloading as

```
success: function(data)
        {   
           if(data == 1) // success
           {
             $('.status-checks').each(function(){
                if($(this).attr(data) == $(current_element).attr('data'))
                {
                   $(this).addClass('btn-success');
                   $(this).text('Paid');
                }
             })
           }else // failed
           {
             $('.status-checks').each(function(){
                if($(this).attr(data) == $(current_element).attr('data'))
                {
                   $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
                   $(this).text('Unpaid');
                }
             })
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: it works but with errors. When you click on the button to update it first change the status but not the button color just the text and when you click on it the second time it wont work i.e change the status and when it changed the status it will affect all buttons with the same color. Please, what do you think might be the problem.

Comment: It didn't work. Please do you know a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

you must replace location.reload() with a if and else statment that for e.g if(data) //button value change else //button value don't change or other statement

that's it